# Why can't I use a script variable as a function parameter in a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, variables

I have the following script variable and a mapping defined as follows:

```
let s:tblgen_files = '-G \"\\.td$\"'
nnoremap <leader>st :call <SID>PrjAck(expand('<cword>'), s:tblgen_files, "-w -Q", proj_root)<cr>
```

When the mapping is execute I get a following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this need to be a script variable? Would a global not work just as well? Maybe a buffer local would work if you need to have a value for only certain files

Comment: @PeterRincker Unfortunately it does need to be a script variable.

Comment: You have stated it needs to be a script local variable but you have not given a reason. I would imagine this parameter should go way and be handled inside of `s:PrjAck` function. I see no advantage of passing it around as a parameter. Especially since, script variable is rather tricky for a user to modify with out some interface.

Comment: @OP Since when does a function argument need to have a specific scope? :)

Comment: @PeterRincker this script is used as part of a project and must stay within a project. That's why I want to make it local. This function is used in multiple places. Placing this variable into this function will change its functionality. Another option is to create a function which would call `s:PrjAck` but I don't see a need to do that.

Comment: On a side note: you do know about the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin, right?

Comment: If still not clear for the @OP - removing the `s:tblgen_files` as function argument, and using it *directly* inside the function (since, being in the same script file, it's visible to it) has the same effect. I'm not sure if it's the *desired* effect ...

Comment: @SatoKatsura Never heard of this plugin.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Seems like CtrlSF is a wrapper around ag/ack. How does it solve the problem?

Comment: `ag` / `ack` are external programs.  `CtrlSF` is a Vim plugin than can use them, or can work without them.  It doesn't solve your problem as you state it above; it does however do something that you seem to want to do with your plugin: search for the word under cursor with `ag`, or `ack`.  You can find more about it reading the docs.  Or you can ignore it, and my tangent.

Comment: It is a good suggestion. I will try to explore this when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

This is (probably) the wrong way to go about this.

### Long answer

Without knowing exactly scenario it is hard to suggest better alternatives. In general script local variables are more of a way to protect and encapsulate variables. Having them in your mapping just seems wrong as your mappings do not change.

Below are some general solutions:

#### Hard coding

If your script local variable never changes and `s:ProjectAck` is always being called with `s:tblgen_files` then equivalent to a hard coded value so remove it from the function call.

#### Global variable

If you script local variable changes and `s:ProjectAck` is always being called with `s:tblgen_files` then this is equivalent to a global variable. Still probably best to put it in the function.

#### Default parameter

`s:ProjectAck` is being called from many places and not always using `s:tblgen_files`. This is a sign of a default value so use a different mechanism. See `:h a:0`

```
function! s:example(...)
  let param = a:0 ? a:1 : 'default value'
endfunction
```

#### Buffer local variable

This is the odd case out because this is not possible with a script local variable, however it is worth mentioning as buffer local variables are often used a way of mimicking a "project local variables".

### You have made it this far: How to use script local variables in mappings

Simple, don't. Use another script local function.

```
function! s:files()
  return s:tblgen_files
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>st :call <SID>PrjAck(expand('<cword>'), <SID>files(), "-w -Q", proj_root)<cr>
```

### Conclusion

I would suggest you figure out your needs and choose an alternative to using a script local variable inside your mapping.